# Renaming variables inside preprocessor directives in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, preprocessor-directive

I've got a convenience problem, where if I want something to be executed only on specific platforms, the compiler stops checking and refactoring the code. So in this scenario, if I refactor `foo` to `bar` in Visual Studio, it will only refactor the `foo = true` part to `bar = true`, but `foo = false` will not be changed.

```
bool foo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    foo = true;
#else
    foo = false;
#endif
```

To avoid that, in some cases I changed the code to

```
bool foo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    foo = true;
    return;
#endif
    foo = false;
```

but that is not only more tedious, because I have to make sure, that I can return after assigning something to `foo`, I also get a warning about unreachable code in the Unity Editor.

So my question is: What is the best way to handle this? Is it possible to make Visual Studio also code-check and refactor code that is not used for the current platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Preprocessor directive used(`UNITY_EDITOR`) used is `true`, the rest of the code in the `#else` and `#elif` statement is now considered as a comment.

This has a simple fix in Visual Studio 2015 and above. When you rename avariable, check the **Include Comments** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, you're really helpful for all my questions!

Comment: However: Is it possible to add syntax checks in the comments?

Comment: The gif shows that the actual in the else clause after confirming is NOT RENAMED! So it does not work as intended

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, pure VS doesn't support that. If you use Resharper, it search for the refactored name literally in scripts and can do what you want. However, it's paid extension. If you don't want to spend any money for that, you can always use `Application.isEditor` or `Application.platform` for your platform-depending code. However, there might be a problem with namespaces existing only when on given platform - i.e `using UnityEngine.iOS` will fail to compile when on Android. I personally avoid preprocessor directives and use them ONLY when there is no other way. So actually the only situation I use preprocessor directives is when I need to use platform specific namespace, like mentioned above `UnityEngine.iOS` or `UnityEditor`

Comment: I have a lot of use cases, where I need platform specific code, so avoiding that is not really an option for me.
I'll have a look at Resharper, but of course I would appreciate free alternatives.

Comment: Yeah, but what about using Application.platform? Doesn't that cover most of your cases?